# Adding box plot for mean point

Tags: r, plot

My data (MafBeta) look like as (original data is 1000 individuals, here i just displayed first 10):

```
    EuMAF       Eubeta
  0.11620 -0.000638786
  0.02020  0.012226700
  0.01515  0.009831800
  0.06229 -0.002261970
  0.04714 -0.006207810
  0.00000  0.000000000
  0.42090 -0.008781820
  0.00000  0.000000000
  0.01852  0.006342230
 0.03199 -0.001722920
```

Wanted to add box plot for each of 6 mean points, I tried this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
forLines <- MafBeta %>% group_by(cut(EuMAF, breaks = 6, labels=F)) %>%
  summarise(mean_beta = mean(Afbeta), mean_maf = mean(EuMAF)) 
p <- ggplot(forLines, aes(x=mean_maf, y=mean_beta)) 
p + geom_point(size=3) + geom_boxplot(aes(group=cut(MafBeta$EuMAF,breaks=6,labels=F))) +
  geom_line(data=forLines,aes(x=mean_maf,y=mean_beta))
```

Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (6): group, x, y

Any suggestion please?

Comment: this makes no sense. Where is the data for notches and whiskers? Try `MafBeta %>% 
  mutate(gr=cut(EuMAF, breaks = 6, labels=F)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(gr), y=Eubeta)) + 
      geom_boxplot()`